# ATU Reports throws NullPointerException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, report, testng

I am trying to use ATU Reports for my project. The suite has around 25 @Test methods. After the completion of execution, a null pointer exception is got.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   java.lang.NullPointe rException
>           at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.onFinish(Unknown Sour
>   ce)
>           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.invokeListeners(SuiteRunner.java:204)
>           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:264)
>           at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>           at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>           at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
>           at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
>           at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
>           at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1355)
>           at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at atu.testng.reports.writers.CurrentRunPageWriter.getTestCaseHTMLPath(U
>   nknown Source)
>           at atu.testng.reports.writers.CurrentRunPageWriter.writeFailedData(Unkno
>   wn Source)
>           at atu.testng.reports.writers.CurrentRunPageWriter.content(Unknown Sourc
>   e)
>           at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.generateCurrentRunPag
>   e(Unknown Source)
>           ... 10 more

Another observation is that the ATU report is generated successfully when the @Test methods is around 5. Could it be that a particular @Test method is causing this NullPointerException?

testng.xml file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
  <groups>
  <run>
  <include name="A1" />
  <include name="A2" />
  <include name="B1" />
  </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
    <class name="com.test.testcases.Class1"/>
      <class name="com.test.testcases.Class2"/>
      <class name="com.test.testcases.Class3"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <listeners>
  <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener"></listener>
  <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ConfigurationListener"></listener>
  <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.MethodListener"></listener>
  </listeners>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: I am calling the listeners from Testng.xml file. 
  <listeners>
  <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener"></listener>
  <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ConfigurationListener"></listener>
  <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.MethodListener"></listener>
  </listeners>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging manually and running the classes individually I found out that one of the class was throwing a nullpointer exception as there was a mismatch in the number of parameters passed.

Answer (score 0):

Something is null in this code (decompiled from ATU 5.1.1):

```
public void onFinish(ISuite paramISuite)
  {
    try
    {
      this.iSuite = paramISuite;
      String str1 = SettingsFile.get("passedList") + this.passedTests.size() + ';';
      String str2 = SettingsFile.get("failedList") + this.failedTests.size() + ';';
      String str3 = SettingsFile.get("skippedList") + this.skippedTests.size() + ';';
      SettingsFile.set("passedList", str1);
      SettingsFile.set("failedList", str2);
      SettingsFile.set("skippedList", str3);
      HTMLDesignFilesJSWriter.lineChartJS(str1, str2, str3, this.runCount);
      HTMLDesignFilesJSWriter.barChartJS(str1, str2, str3, this.runCount);
      HTMLDesignFilesJSWriter.pieChartJS(this.passedTests.size(), this.failedTests.size(), this.skippedTests.size(), this.runCount);
      generateIndexPage();
      paramISuite.setAttribute("endExecution", Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
      long l = ((Long)paramISuite.getAttribute("startExecution")).longValue();
      generateConsolidatedPage();
      generateCurrentRunPage(l, System.currentTimeMillis());
      startReportingForPassed(this.passedTests);
      startReportingForFailed(this.failedTests);
      startReportingForSkipped(this.skippedTests);
      if (Directory.generateExcelReports) {
        ExcelReports.generateExcelReport(Directory.RUNDir + Directory.SEP + "(" + Directory.REPORTSDIRName + ") " + Directory.RUNName + this.runCount + ".xlsx", this.passedTests, this.failedTests, this.skippedTests);
      }
      if (Directory.generateConfigReports) {
        ConfigurationListener.startConfigurationMethodsReporting(this.runCount);
      }
      if (Directory.recordSuiteExecution) {
        try
        {
          this.recorder.stop();
        }
        catch (Throwable localThrowable) {}
      }
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      throw new IllegalStateException(localException);
    }
  }
```

I suspect the issue comes from `long l = ((Long)paramISuite.getAttribute("startExecution")).longValue();` because TestNG has some issues with listeners.

What you should do is installing a java decompiler in your IDE (for example http://jd.benow.ca/). Then, in debug mode, you'll be able to find where exactly is the issue.

You should try the latest TestNG version (6.9.12) too which is supposed to fix the previous listener issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While debugging manually and running the classes individually I found out that one of the class was throwing a nullpointer exception as there was a mismatch in the number of parameters passed. I will install a decompiler so that I am better equipped with debugging such issues in the future.

Comment: Ok! You should reply to yourself and to close the question then ;)